# Generating an equal number of random integers in response to a previous input in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

I'm trying to create a random number matrix in matlab. However, I'm struggling a little with the logic of some of it. What I want is this:

I need it to loop through a predefined random matrix (2 rows, n columns) 50% of which are 1's and 50% are 0's (I can already do this part). Everytime it encounters a 1 it should then enter another loop which puts a 1,2,3 or 4 in the corresponding position in the second row. However (and this is the part I'm struggling with) I need it to have an equal number of 1's, 2's, 3's and 4's in the second row. So for example:

The matrix n = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0; 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] should run through the script and produce something like: n = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 0, 0]

This is what I have so far:

```
function pureToneTimer
ptpschedule = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0]
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
d = 0;
x = length(ptpschedule)/4
for n = 1:length(ptpschedule) 
    if ptpschedule(1,n) == 1
        while a < x && b < x && c < x && d < x
        i = randi(4)
        ptpschedule(2,n) = i;
        switch i
            case 1
                a = a + 1;
            case 2
                b = b + 1;
            case 3
                c = c + 1;
            case 4
                d = d + 1;
        end
        end
    end
end
assignin('caller', 'ptpschedule', ptpschedule)
end
```

Sorry if this turns out to be a really trivial question. I'm just struggling to wrap my head around it!

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: Do you want 1--4 in the columns where the first row has a zero (as you say in the text) or in all columns (as in your example)?

Comment: Hi Luis, sorry I made an error in the example. I've corrected it now, 1-4 should be where the first row has a 1. As in the text.

Comment: And is the number of `1` in the first row guaranteed to be a multiple of `4`? What to do if it's not?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean? Everytime there is a 1, below it should randomly be inserted  a 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. Provided that the end matrix has an equal number of 1, 2, 3, and 4. So, in an example involving 16 numbers, there should be two of each 1,2,3,4 in the second row (as there will be 8 number 1's in the first row).

Comment: What if there are 17 numbers?

Comment: Oh right! Sorry, yes it is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
V = 4; %// number of values you want. 4 in your example
ind = ptpschedule(1,:)>0; %// logical index of positive values in the first row
n = nnz(ind);
vals = mod(0:n-1, V)+1; %// values to be randomly thrown in.
    %// This guarantees the same number of each value if n is a multiple of V
ptpschedule(2,ind) = vals(randperm(n)); %// fill values in second row in random order
```

- If the number of `1`'s in the first row is a multiple of `V`, this generates each value `1`, `2`, ... `V` the same number of times in the second row.
- Otherwise, some values in the second row will appear once more than other values.

Example:

```
ptpschedule = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
V = 4;
```

produces

```
ptpschedule =
     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     0
     0     3     0     4     2     1     0     0
```